# How do i get entire object in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im creating an app with Firebase database here is my data structure:

```
{
  "teachers" : {
    "USYSacnOjDR5EAPwljZMHtggN9I2" : {
      "name" : {
        "teacher_name" : "Alison"
      },
      "members": {
        "sIrfMA3bm0R9uj55nDUFpFyabcL2" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "sIrfMA3bm0R9uj55nDUFpFyabcL2" : {
      "position" : {
        "bpos" : "0"
      },
      "name" : {
        "email" : "m@m.com",
        "name" : "John",
        "surname" : "Clash"
      }
    }
```

So now in `RecyclerView` im trying to display all of the `Alison` teacher members, as you can see `John Clash` is set to `true`. Anyway when i try to retrieve user this way:

```
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teachers").child(teacherkey).child("members");
reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                User user = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(User.class);
                result.add(user);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                User user = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(User.class);
                result.remove(user);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

the app crash because of NPE, datasnapshot key is valid, it is John's account key but value of snapshot is `true`. How can i solve that and get from John's data `name` and `surname`?

@Edit: 
Here is my retrieving code:

```
 public void updateList() {
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String userId = ds.getKey();
                    DatabaseReference userIdRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);
                    userIdRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            User user = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(User.class);
                            result.add(user);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: as https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ says, your json is invalid, paste your json structure there and you will see that you are missing some points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, you need to query your database twice. Please see the code below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference membersRef = rootRef.child(teachers).child(teacherId).child("members");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userId = ds.key();

            DatabaseReference userIdRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userId);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", user.getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            userIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
membersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: this should be marked as answer, its just what you need !

Comment: Thanks @GastónSaillén !

Comment: Looks nice but there is one more problem.. So it looks like it works, it reads all specific user data, but when it comes to put it to `recyclerview` app crash and show this error `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right `DatabaseReference`?

Comment: Remove this child -> `.child("name")`.

Comment: removed and got this  `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String`

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your real database.

Comment: Actually this happens because there is this child(userID) in second `reference` when i delete this, `recyclerview` keeps updating with new items, every `key` of this item is its firebase `userid`, but when i add `child(userID)` at the end of reference the key of this item is first `child` in users data..

Comment: You need to use that userId. Should work, I have tested myself this code.

Comment: Allright, it retrieve data correctly but only when the second retrieve is retrieved by ValueEventListener i read that there is huge different between this and  ChildEventListener. Anyway @AlexMamo You are the best, huge thanks for help and your time!

Comment: Good to hear that it worked! You're welcome! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 approaches to solve this issue:

a.) Inside onChildAdded you already have, if the value you got is true, do another search in database, but this time in "users" node. Something like

```
newReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(dataSnapshot.getKey).child("name")
```

b.) In the "members" node, write "John Clash" instead of "true". This approach will work for now, but you will fall into the first approach if someday you need to retrieve email address as well

Comment: Option b. is right out, option a. sounds nice thanks :)